# Postgresql:- Write Query statement in a string with Table name in a double Quotes

Tags: c#, postgresql

[image]I'm able to connect to postgresQL but while writing the query string having issue .

I'm trying below,

```
        string queryString = "Select* From \"ContactLink\" where \"ContactApplicationID\"="+ contactAppID;
```

Output :- "Select* From \"ContactLink\" where \"ContactApplicationID\"=1428760"

this one is returning the string with \ with table name "ContactLink" and ContactApplicationID.

I want the queryString with Double quotes without . How can i do that ?

I have tried string.Replace and all but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated .

Note:- When we print the "queryString " it is coming without /. so dont know what is going on there.

Reason for complaint is because it does the connection but it is not able to read the Table .

Comment: @GrantWinney but if we execute the query without double quotes in postgresql it is throwing error .

Comment: @GrantWinney Its throwing syntax error .

Comment: @GrantWinney :- I've attached the screengrab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127507/discussion-between-vic-and-grant-winney).

Comment: @GrantWinney :- its not working

Comment: Standard SQL uses double quotes for identifiers so `"Select * From \"ContactLink\" where \"ContactApplicationID\"="+ contactAppID` should work fine. Single quotes are for string literals so `"Select * From 'ContactLink' where 'ContactApplicationID'="+ contactAppID` doesn't make any sense and won't work. What exactly is the problem? What does "I want the queryString with Double quotes without ." mean?

Comment: Select * from dbo."ContactLink" where "ContactApplicationID"=1428760

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from ContactLink where ContractApplicationID = 1428
```

or if it's a string field

```
Select * from ContactLink where ContractApplicationID = '1428'
```

If you are trying in c# code then try:

```
 string queryString = String.Format("Select * From ContactLink where ContactApplicationID = {0} ",contactAppID);
```

Comment: :- Error is at per attached screengrab

Comment: What is the error when you used the syntax I suggested?

Comment: Samekind of error man . Let me know if you need screen grab for that as well ?

Comment: You need the double quotes around the table and column names since SQL is case insensitive otherwise; standard SQL folds identifiers to upper case, PostgreSQL folds them to lower case. Without the double quotes you'll get complaints about "`contactlink` being an unknown table" and "`contractapplicationid` being an unknown column".

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the way you created the table. Your table name and columns in it were created as case sensitive that is "supported" in sql but can cause a lot problems in sql and a language that you use to write query. In sql it has to be escaped with double quotes.

In sql is common to use _ instead of mixture of upper a lower case letters to split words.

ContactLink = contact_link
ContactApplicationID = contact_application_id

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the naming convention.